# Why does fabdep keep asking to open port 111 even if it is open?

Tags: blockchain, private-blockchain, hyperledger-fabric, ports

Trying to set up a hyperledger fabric blockchain with [fabdep](https://www.fabricdeployer.com/) but it seems to not work and I'm stuck on an error saying that port 111 is closed and not open.

`PLAY [127.0.0.1] *************************************************************** TASK [remove ssh_keygen old] *************************************************** ok: [127.0.0.1] PLAY [all] ********************************************************************* TASK [Gathering Facts] ********************************************************* ok: [192.168.1.203] PLAY [all] ********************************************************************* TASK [Install Nmap] ************************************************************ ok: [192.168.1.203] TASK [Check if script is already present] ************************************** changed: [192.168.1.203] TASK [Transfer the script] ***************************************************** changed: [192.168.1.203] TASK [Run script] ************************************************************** [WARNING]: As of Ansible 2.4, the parameter 'executable' is no longer supported with the 'command' module. Not using '/bin/bash'. changed: [192.168.1.203] TASK [Ports Status] ************************************************************ ok: [192.168.1.203] => { "msg": [ "@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@", "@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@ Looking for required ports @@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@", "@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@", "port 443 avaialable", "port 6443 avaialable", "port 10251 avaialable", "port 10252 avaialable", "port 10250 avaialable", "open the port 111 for futher steps.Port 111 required for NFS service." ] } TASK [Check if script is already present] ************************************** changed: [192.168.1.203] TASK [copy the output to a local file] ***************************************** changed: [192.168.1.203] TASK [ports check] ************************************************************* fatal: [192.168.1.203]: FAILED! => {"changed": true, "cmd": "grep open /tmp/ports.txt", "delta": "0:00:00.001586", "end": "2020-11-28 18:46:02.934891", "failed_when_result": true, "rc": 0, "start": "2020-11-28 18:46:02.933305", "stderr": "", "stderr_lines": [], "stdout": "open the port 111 for futher steps.Port 111 required for NFS service.", "stdout_lines": ["open the port 111 for futher steps.Port 111 required for NFS service."]} PLAY RECAP`

But I'm sure that port 111 is open and listening as in the NMaps output I see:

```
ubuntutwo@ubuntutwo:~$ nmap -p 1-65535 192.168.1.203

Starting Nmap 7.80 ( https://nmap.org ) at 2020-11-28 18:51 +06

Nmap scan report for ubuntutwo (192.168.1.203)

Host is up (0.000039s latency).

Not shown: 65526 closed ports

PORT      STATE SERVICE

22/tcp    open  ssh

111/tcp   open  rpcbind

617/tcp   open  sco-dtmgr

2049/tcp  open  nfs

3002/tcp  open  exlm-agent

43295/tcp open  unknown

45517/tcp open  unknown

48003/tcp open  nimgtw

52971/tcp open  unknown

Nmap done: 1 IP address (1 host up) scanned in 0.63 seconds
```

Here I see port 111 is open and listening.

Any help is appreciated, thank you!